# Gestionando con Git un proyecto que se encuentra entre dos carpetas

Tags: git, github

He creado dos carpetas, A y B que en principio tienen que ver con proyectos diferentes, A y B pero yo quiero juntarlos, porque para mí son el mismo proyecto, porque comparten muchos archivos y porque están relacionados con lo mismo, un tutorial de Angular que estoy siguiendo. Estaba trabajando con la carpeta A, hice un commit y después me fui a la carpeta B, hice un `git init` y empecé a comitear los cambios, el problema lo tengo cuando voy a hacer un git pull:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=GuillermoBaldan/<branch> master
```

La verdad es que no entiendo muy bien lo que está pasando. Si alguien me lo puede explicar...

Comment: pero las dos capetas estan hacie el mismo repositorio? puedes ver el repositorio de un proyecto con git remote -v

Comment: Es necesario que conozcas el concepto de ramas o branch. Entra a la carpeta del proyecto A, crea una rama y haz un push del proyecto B, posteriormente intenta hacer un merge de ambas ramas(la rama donde se encuentra el proyecto A, y la nueva rama que creaste donde pusiste el proyecto B) Si consigues un FastForward los proyectos se habrán fusionado de manera exitosa, caso contrario deberás resolver los conflictos que git haya encontrado en el código. 

https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Ramificaciones-en-Git-Procedimientos-b%C3%A1sicos-para-ramificar-y-fusionar

Comment: pero el proyecto B, tiene un master remoto en algun lado? por lo que contas, no hiciste ningun push a ningun lado...